# tensorflow: block-wise array/matrix sums

Tags: tensorflow

Is there any tensorflow function that allows one to do block-wise sums on an array or matrix.

For example, if I have an array

```
tf.constant(np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6]))
```

I need to return an array of sums of blocks of `2` elements. In other words, the sums of `1 + 2, 3 + 4` and `5 + 6` in an array.

```
np.array([3,7,11])
```

Comment: Do a convolution with a filter `[1, 1]` and do not train that filter. Also, set `stride = 2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `tf.reshape` and `tf.reduce_sum` as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
n=tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5,6])
res=tf.reduce_sum(tf.reshape(n,(3,2)),1)
sess=tf.Session()
res.eval(session=sess)
```

This prints `array([ 3,  7, 11])`

In the general case, if you want to get the sums of disjoint sequences of `k` elements, replace `tf.reshape(n,(3,2))` with `tf.reshape(n,(-1,k))`. (The -1 will force it to specify the number of rows to `n/k`).